# How to export a variable to another react functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, export

I am creating this react app in which I want to export a variable to another react functional component. I am also facing an issue since when a user clicks on a button, only then will the variable contain value or else it is undefined and exporting an undefined variable is not possible. So I was hoping that there is a way I can export the variable only when it contains a value. Thanks in advance to anyone who has helped!

PS: I am a Beginner :)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

if this variable is defined inside your the function of your component you can't export it

```
const canExport = 'yes we can'

const App = () => {
    const iAmImpossibleToExport = []

    return <div>The application</div>
}
export { canExport }

export default App
```

If you want to pass variables to other components, you can use props, context, redux.... but it's more advanced topics (redux and context) and tools that should be manipulated and used carefully. You probably juste need state and props at your level.

Good luck with you journey into React

Comment: Thanks for your help! :)